# Генерация ключа к элементу много мерного массива

Tags: php, массивы

Доброго времени есть у меня массив например выглядит от так:

$array;

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( 
      [name] => Dan 
      [YO] => 34 
   ) 
   [1] => Array ( 
      [name] => Steve 
      [YO] => 22 
   ) 
   [2] => Array ( 
      [name] => Mike 
      [YO] => 27 
   ) 
)
```

это просто пример как может выглядеть массив - предположим ключи для работы с ним мне передаются строкой например так 0-name   2-YO

как я могу из строк сгенерировать путь к эелменту масив? я знаю что можно строкой сгенерировать php код и выполнить его через eval() но как по мне это костыль

массив может быть более мложный но ключи всегда передаются для него строкой

есть ли какой то способ сгенерировать путь к конкретному элементу например что бы это выглядело как то так

```
echo $array[$path];  - при сусловии что это было бы эквивалентно например $array[0]['name']
```

?

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = Array ( 
   0 => Array ( 
      'name' => 'Dan', 
      'YO' => 34,
   ), 
   1 => Array ( 
      'name' => 'Steve', 
      'YO' => 22 
   ), 
   2 => Array ( 
      'name' => 'Mike', 
      'YO' => 27 
   )
);

$data = '0-name 2-YO';
$paths = explode(' ', $data);

foreach ($paths as $idx => $item) {
    $path = explode('-', $item);
    $itemsData[$idx] = [];
    foreach( $path as $value ) {
        if ( count($itemsData[$idx]) > 0 ) {
            $itemsData[$idx] = $itemsData[$idx][$value];
        } else {
            $itemsData[$idx] = $array[$value];
        }
    }
}

var_dump($itemsData); // array("Dan",27)
```

Ничего сложного. Разбиваем строку на отдельные части - искомые данные, потом уже эти искомые данные разбиваем на отдельные части - ключи в массиве данных, и ищем данные используюя эти же ключи

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array ( 
   0 => array ( 
      'name' => 'Dan', 
      'YO' => 34,
   ), 
   1 => array ( 
      'name' => 'Steve', 
      'YO' => 22 
   ), 
   2 => array ( 
      'name' => 'Mike', 
      'YO' => array('a' => 33, 'b' => 44)
   )
);


function path(& $a, $path)
{
    foreach(explode('-', $path) as $p)
    {
        if(isset($a[$p])) $a =& $a[$p];
        else return null;
    }
    return $a;
}

var_dump(path($array, '2-YO-a')); // int(33)
var_dump(path($array, '5-YO')); // NULL
```